# Multiple Resource Files .resx in one project at runtime

Tags: silverlight, xaml, localization, resources, resx

I am using silver light 4 and for XAML text blocks binding i want to use multiple resource file but unable to implement it. one link is supporting the concept of not having multiple resource file of same language at runtime dynamically

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650657.aspx[^]

i m using the following code for binding a text block using 1 resource file

where ResourceKey is the key defined at App.xaml and CNICNumberTextBlock is the name defined in resource file

App.xaml key defining:

Kindly help me to make use of multiple resource file at run time

Answer (score 0):

I have came across some links which might be useful to u..

[Localisation - Michael Snow](http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/04/28/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-7-localized-resources/)

[Jeff Prosise Blog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/06/21/dynamic-localization-in-silverlight.aspx)